# Can't open multiple Modules

Tags: vb.net, module

I'm writing a Application where i need to list multiple Modules.
The Problem is that every Module i load, is the actually the first Module i have loaded.

Function to open a Module:

```
Public Function openModule(path As String) As ctxModule.ctxModule
    Dim asm As Assembly = Nothing
    Dim myType As System.Type = Nothing
    Dim implementsIPlugin As Boolean = Nothing
    Try
        asm = Assembly.LoadFrom(path)
        Dim fullClassName As String = "Main"
        myType = asm.GetType(fullClassName)
        implementsIPlugin = GetType(ctxModule.ctxModule).IsAssignableFrom(myType)
        If implementsIPlugin Then
            Return Activator.CreateInstance(myType)
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
    Return Nothing
End Function
```

The code which calls the function:

```
Public Sub load_modules()
    modules.Clear()
    modulePaths.Clear()
    For Each F As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles(path_modules)
        If F.EndsWith(".03MDL") Then
            Dim m As ctxModule.ctxModule = Nothing
            m = openModule(F)
            If IsNothing(m) = False Then
                modules.Add(m)
                modulePaths.Add(m, F)
            Else : End If
            m = Nothing
        Else : End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Every Module inthe List "modules" is the the First Module. So the list looks like this:

- Module 1
- Module 1
- Module 1

But i should look like this:

- Module 1
- Module 2
- Module 3

Hope someone can help :S

Comment: Does `path` contain a different value each time `openModule` is called?

Comment: yes, to a other module ^^

Comment: do no one know, how i can fix this ? :S

Comment: Maybe the problem is on load_modules. I assume that are different .03MDL files, that work like dll. But from where comes the "Module X" inside the list i'm not getting it. Can you post each itineration of the For in the load_modules? just the path please.